# What products come from the electrolysis of sodium bicarbonate?

Tags: electrolysis

I did an experiment finding the electrolysis of various solutions. One of them was sodium bicarbonate and tap water. I want to be able to scientifically explain my results, using chemical equations and explanations of those equations. Can somebody help?

-Thanks